# overridePendingTransition method in Adapter in Android

Tags: java, android

i want use **`overridePendingTransition`** method in my Custom Adapter, unfortunately, this method does not detect!!! 
I use it as follows:

```
v.getContext().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_out, R.anim.fade_in);
```

I started to put activity into an adapter,for this reason I want to run this method in Adapter.

my custom adapter codes :

```
public class levels_card_adapter extends
        RecyclerView.Adapter<levels_card_adapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context mContext;
    Activity activity = (Activity) mContext;

    private static String[] adapter_levels_number;

    public levels_card_adapter(String[] adapter_levels_num_data) {
        adapter_levels_number = adapter_levels_num_data;


    }

    @Override
    public levels_card_adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                             int viewType) {

        View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.levels_recycler_layout, null);


        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

        viewHolder.adapter_levels_text.setText(adapter_levels_number[position].toString());

        viewHolder.adapter_levels_version = adapter_levels_number[position];
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return adapter_levels_number.length;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView adapter_levels_text;

        public String adapter_levels_version;


        public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
            super(itemLayoutView);

            adapter_levels_text = (TextView) itemLayoutView
                    .findViewById(R.id.level_thumnail_text);


            itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent question_page_intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), com.tellfa.braingame.activities.question_Page.class);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(question_page_intent);
                    v.getContext().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_out, R.anim.fade_in);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

my custom adapter new codes :

```
public class levels_card_adapter extends
        RecyclerView.Adapter<levels_card_adapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context mContext;
    Activity activity = (Activity) mContext;

    private static String[] adapter_levels_number;

    public levels_card_adapter(Activity activity, String[] adapter_levels_num_data) {
        this.activity = activity;
        adapter_levels_number = adapter_levels_num_data;
    }

    @Override
    public levels_card_adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                             int viewType) {

        View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.levels_recycler_layout, null);


        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

        viewHolder.adapter_levels_text.setText(adapter_levels_number[position].toString());

        viewHolder.adapter_levels_version = adapter_levels_number[position];

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return adapter_levels_number.length;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView adapter_levels_text;

        public String adapter_levels_version;



        public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
            super(itemLayoutView);

            adapter_levels_text = (TextView) itemLayoutView
                    .findViewById(R.id.level_thumnail_text);


            itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent question_page_intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), com.tellfa.braingame.activities.question_Page.class);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(question_page_intent);
                    activity.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_out, R.anim.fade_in);

                }
            });
        }

    }
```

How do i use this (**overridePendingTransition**) method in the adapter?

Comment: `overridePendingTransition` has **nothing** to do with the adapter, its an `Activity` method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`overridePendingTransition` is a method of the `Activity`. You already have the activity `context` as member variable. You could use that.

```
Intent question_page_intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), com.tellfa.braingame.activities.question_Page.class);
activity.startActivity(question_page_intent);
activity.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_out, R.anim.fade_in);
```

Also make sure you are initializing `activity` in constructor.

```
public levels_card_adapter(Activity activity,String[] adapter_levels_num_data) {
   this.activity  =activity;    
   adapter_levels_number = adapter_levels_num_data;
  }
```

Comment: tnx my dear bro , i told you the code i added to my codes, but show error for this word "activity" !!! Is it possible you edit my codes and i use this? thanks

Comment: Error is not static (activity) and static the "this.activity  =activity;" code cont accept

Comment: tnx for your help my dear friend <3. New code in the above, put "my custom adapter new codes :"

Comment: change `private static String[] adapter_levels_number;` to `private String[] adapter_levels_number;`. Remove static